# Laravel 8 permission denied in shared hosting

Tags: laravel, cpanel

I have my laravel 8 app hosted in hostinger hpanel but for hours I have trying to fix this error.

`UnexpectedValueException There is no existing directory at "There is no existing directory at "/Users/macbookpro/Documents/Theodory/projectName/storage/logs" and it could not be created: Permission denied" and it could not be created: Permission denied` missing folder is from my machine instead of cpanel path.

I have tried find and delete `../bootstrap/cache/config.php` but there is no such a file and I have tried to delete all `storage/logs` but am still getting that error and I have tried to add manually in `web.php`

```
Route::get('/optimize',function(){
 Artisan::class('optimize:clear');

});
```

But when I hit `/optimize` am still getting the same error.

I have decided to use hostinger `ssh` so that I can be able to run `artisan` commands but am still getting same error even after hitting `artisan` commands successful.

What can I make it work in hostinger hpanel to which is similar to traditional cpanel.

Answer (score 0):

try the following commands and hit again `/optimize`

```
php artisan route:clear

php artisan config:clear

php artisan cache:clear
```

Comment: See my update question on the missing folder is pointing to my local machine instead of cpanel location.

Answer (score 0):

try these artisan commands

```
php artisan optimize:clear
```

after that, you should run this command

```
php artisan optimize
```

Answer (score 0):

you are facing this issue because your application doesn't have proper permissions for the storage directory.

Use this command to grant required permissions to the storage directory, and this should resolve the issue.

chmod 777 -R storage/

Comment: See my updated question @rahul I have noticed missing folder has path of my local machine instead of cpanel path.